# Change Image view height and width programmatically based on drawable images

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I want to change the Imageview Height and width based on the drawable image size 
programmatically? i have two types of images one is horizontal and another one is vertical. By default i have write my xml code  for vertical images but i want to change Image view height and width for horizontal images by java code. how to do this ?

my xml code is

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:paddingTop="47dp"
    android:paddingBottom="48dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/flipcardWrapper">

    <ImageView
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="365dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgtrans"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

and my java code to change height and width of image view is

```
imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtrans);
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
    int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
    int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();



    if(d.getIntrinsicHeight()==797 && d.getIntrinsicWidth()==1218)
    {
        imgtrans.getLayoutParams().width=300;
        imgtrans.requestLayout();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set two images for horizontal and another one is vertical in drawable .then find screen orientation based on it set image

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagehorizontal);
//set your other properties
}

if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imagevertical);
//set your other properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT in java code.

```
imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtrans);
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
int h = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
int w = d.getIntrinsicWidth();



if(d.getIntrinsicHeight()==797 && d.getIntrinsicWidth()==1218)
{
    imgtrans.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    imgtrans.getLayoutParams().height = someValue;
    imgtrans.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: isHori(d) i could not find this in android. can you tell me how to achieve this

Comment: @user7125006 Sorry my english is so poor,I can not express clearly.So I modified my answer.